# Run code only if process last for more than 500 ms

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to debug a quite rare and random timeout on a NodeJs AWS Lambda.
To see what processes are still running I'll use packages from this thread [How can I get a list of callbacks in the Node work queue? (or, Why won't Node exit?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17960452/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-callbacks-in-the-node-work-queue-or-why-wont-node-ex).
To avoid useless logs, I want to log callbacks only in the process run for more than 500ms.
Is it possible to do that and how ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like

```
var to = setTimeout(function(){ <log> }, 500); //log in 500ms
```

And then at the end of command you can do:

```
clearTimeout(to);
```

That way it would call log in half a second, unless it lasted less than 500 and called cleartimeout.